# What's the most efficient jQuery way to check/toggle fading of three elements?

Tags: jquery

I've got three sidebar buttons. On a click event, each opens a previously hidden div:

```
//Contribute Sidebar Actions
      $('#contributePod .facebookBtn, #contributeFacebook .close').click(function() {
          $('#contributeFacebook').fadeToggle('slow', function() {
        });
      });

      $('#contributePod .twitterBtn, #contributeTwitter .close').click(function() {
          $('#contributeTwitter').fadeToggle('slow', function() {
        });
      });

      $('#contributePod .flickrBtn, #contributeFlickr .close').click(function() {
          $('#contributeFlickr').fadeToggle('slow', function() {
        });
      });
```

Here is the HTML portion

```
<div id="contributePod">
            <h2>Contribute</h2>
            <a class="facebookBtn" href="#" title="Contribute on Facebook"></a>
            <a class="twitterBtn" href="#" title="Contribute on Twitter"></a>
            <a class="flickrBtn" href="#" title="Contribute on Flickr"></a>
        </div>


        <div class="contributeContainer" id="contributeFacebook">
            <a class="close" href="#">X</a>
            <h2>Contribute on Facebook</h2>

            <p>
                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit.
            </p>

            <form method="post" action="" id="facebookForm" name="facebook_form">
                <label>Comment</label>
                <textarea name="facebookComment" rows="1" cols="1"></textarea>
                <input class="contribSubmit btn" type="submit" value="Share" />
            </form>
        </div> 

        <div class="contributeContainer" id="contributeTwitter">
            <a class="close" href="#">X</a>
            <h2>Contribute on Twitter</h2>

            <p>
                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit.
            </p>

            <form method="post" action="" id="twitterForm" name="twitter_form">
                <label>Comment</label>
                <textarea name="twitterComment" rows="1" cols="1"></textarea>
                <input class="contribSubmit btn" type="submit" value="Share" />
            </form>
        </div> 

        <div class="contributeContainer" id="contributeFlickr">
            <a class="close" href="#">X</a>
            <h2>Contribute on Flickr</h2>

            <p>
                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit.
            </p>

            <form method="post" action="" id="flickrForm" name="flickr_form">
                <input class="btn" type="file" />
            </form>
        </div>
```

1) Is the way I'm doing that the most efficient?

2) What would I add to make it so that if one of the divs is toggled on, and a user clicks to toggle a second, that it fades out the first opened one before showing the second div?

Comment: Can you please post your HTML as well?

Comment: I'd start with: `var contributePod = $("#contributePod");`

Comment: @Keefer Much appreciated! Taking a look at it now.

Comment: ok i think my answer should work below

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's my crack at it: http://jsfiddle.net/Skooljester/FJKz7/. I had to add a `name` value to your `a` tags, but the function was shortened a decent amount.

Comment: This is the solution I used. But two things:
1. In HTML5, the name attribute is obsolete. Is there another attribue I could add?

2. This doesn't allow me to toggle pressing the .facebookBtn again for example.

Comment: To address the name being obsolete, I changed it to look at the href value `var aSource = $(this).attr("href");
        $(".contributeContainer").fadeOut("fast");
        $("#"+aSource).fadeIn("slow");` and the links look like this now `<a class="facebookBtn" href="contributeFacebook" title="Contribute on Facebook"></a>`

Comment: Oh and to prevent the href from firing, I disabled their default action:
`$('#socialScroller a, #contributePod a').click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
    });`

Comment: I would suggest using `data-name` instead of `name`. I will look into the extra toggling part.

Comment: That works and still validates. And thanks for looking at the toggling.

Comment: So that updated code now is `$("#contributePod a").click(function(){
        var aData = $(this).attr("data-name");
        $(".contributeContainer").fadeOut("fast");
        $("#"+aData).fadeIn("slow");
    });`

Answer (score 0):

this should work

change html to:

```
<div id="contributePod">
            <h2>Contribute</h2>
            <a class="contributeFacebook" href="#" title="Contribute on Facebook"></a>
            <a class="contributeTwitter" href="#" title="Contribute on Twitter"></a>
            <a class="contributeFlickr" href="#" title="Contribute on Flickr"></a>
</div>
```

and Javascript:

```
$("#contributePod a").click(function(){
      var which = $(this).attr("class");
      var $container = $("#"+which);

      $container.siblings().is(":visible").fadeOut("slow",function(){
      });

      $container.fadeIn('slow',function(){
      });

      return false;
});

$(".contributeContainer .close").click(function(){
      $(this).parent().fadeOut("slow",function(){
       });

      return false;
});
```

Comment: just saw the html gimme a sec to look it over

Comment: you will have to change ur btn css class stylings from the original names to the changed ones here, but this is a really easy

Answer (score 0):

this should work also

```
$('#contributePod .facebookBtn, #contributeFacebook .close').toggle(
    function() {
        $('#contributeFacebook').fadeIn('slow');
         //more stuff
    },
    function() {
        $('#contributeFacebook').fadeOut('slow');
         //more stuff
    }
);
```